# Displaying individual elements from a .json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to grab elements (using a `localhost`) from a `.json` file in javascript.

I then want to append that data to a button. Appending a variable to a button, header and so on is not a big deal I know how to do that.

My main question is the *ability to grab `JSON` data from a `.json` file within my JavaScript file*.

```
function loadData() {
    $.getJSON('jData.json', function(json) {
        console.log(json); // this will show the object in the console.
    });
}
```

Here are the scripts in my html file.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" ></script>
<script src="jData.json" ></script>

Comment: Do not post your code as an image and instead post it as a `code-snippet` or a `code-block` as links die over time.

Comment: You are already displaying the JSON data. Use as you like. What was the question?

Comment: Apologies I am new to posting on stackOverflow. I think what I am asking is how do I display a variable from my JSON file  in console.log? So not the entire object just the name variable for example? I run into errors when parsing also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate keys in `JSON` you can use `jQuery`'s [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method.

---

```js
function loadData() {
  $.getJSON('jData.json', function(json) {
    $.each(json, (i, el) => {
      console.log(el); // Individual elements
    });
  });
}
```

**Working Example:**

---

```js
$(document).on('click', '.close', (e) => {
  $(e.target).parent().hide('slow', function(){$(e.target).parent().remove(); });;
});

function loadData() {
  $.getJSON('https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bOXjMGvgZe?indent=2', function(json) {
    $.each(json, (i, el) => {
      $('.tags').append(`<span class="tag">${el.key}<span class="close">x</span></span>`);
    });
  });
}

loadData();
```

```css
.tags {
  padding: 20px;
}

.tag {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2.5px;
  background: #34495e;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.tag > .close {
  float: right;
  background: #e74c3c;
  padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags"></div>
```

Comment: Ahhh I understand this! So in terms of getting json data and then appending it to a button, I have to parse it first right? I have run into some errors when parsing. My main goal is grab the json data then append it to some sort of tag...

Comment: @CallumWalsh Yes. You have to parse it first individually unless you want to access the data individually such as `data[0].someProperty.someChildProperty`. Check the working example I've posted. It might help.